# Which is faster? 1 Million lines array or database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, file

In a PHP script, I got a set of params (zip codes / addresses) that will not change frequently, so I'm looking to move this particular db table to a config file. Would it be faster reading a file containing an array with 1 million lines with zip codes as keys or a db table to scan and get the remaining items of the address (street, city, state).

Thanks,

Comment: Database will always be faster.

Comment: If the field is indexed then for sure.

Comment: @Rupam That is not always true. Depending on how you index the db it could be slower.

Comment: If you're using PHP with some kind of accelerator and had that array in the shared memory space I'd say it's OK to use an array. In any other case DB would be faster.

Comment: Rather than worry about "faster", especially without defining how fast you need it, worry about which one is easier to maintain, easier for the programmer, and most importantly, most likely to be correct.  "Faster" should be at the bottom of your priority list below those three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to store data in database rather than file.for million line i guess database if faster than file.

if you want to achieve performance you can use cache like APCCache or use index in databse over zip field.

sphinx is opensource index which allows faster performance over text search.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the number of zip codes I'd say go with the DB instead of the associative array. And you'll be able to search either addresses or zip codes or even ids.